# How do I insert the objective function with absolute value in Gurobi using Java language?

Tags: java, gurobi, absolute-value, objective-function

My objective function is like min|XyPiy-XkPik| i=1...10, j=1...4, k=5...8

I tried to write the code like this, but I don't know what to do with the module

```
GRBLinExpr obj = new GRBLinExpr();
for(int y=1; y<=4; y++) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            obj.addTerm(pij[i][y], xij[i][y]);
        }
    }
    for(int k=5; k<=8; k++) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            obj.addTerm(-pij[i][k], xij[i][k]);
        }
    }
    model.setObjective(obj);
    model.set(GRB.IntAttr.ModelSense, GRB.MINIMIZE);
```

It's one of my first exercises and I don't know how to do it, I hope someone can help me

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you have tried to write.  Without seeing that, we don’t know what your knowledge level is, so any answer would require starting with the basics of Java itself, which would make it a very long answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an auxiliary variable that takes the value of the objective term. Then, you can define a new general constraint for the absolute value of this auxiliary variable: [GRBModel.addGenConstrAbs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/java_model_agc_abs.html#javamethod:GRBModel.addGenConstrAbs)

The resultant of this constraint (which is yet another auxiliary variable) can then be put into the objective function to be minimized.

```
GRBVar objvar = model.addVar(-GRB.INFINITY, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS);
GRBVar absobj = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 1.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS);
GRBLinExpr obj = new GRBLinExpr();

for(int y=1; y<=4; y++) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        obj.addTerm(pij[i][y], xij[i][y]);
    }
}
for(int k=5; k<=8; k++) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        obj.addTerm(-pij[i][k], xij[i][k]);
    }
}

model.addConstr(objvar, GRB.EQUAL, obj, "obj constraint");
model.addGenConstrAbs(absobj, objvar, "abs obj");
```

Here, you don't even need to set the objective anymore, because the only objective coefficient is already defined when adding variable `absobj` (the third argument).

Comment: I tried to add the changes but I print this error Error code: 10003. Invalid constraint sense: 'ÿ'
indicating the objvar line